# when passed StateValue & actionTypes to Search.js -> Object is not iterable

Tags: reactjs

This is the error and i don't see any error please help me to fix it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ktt.png)

**Code**

```
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import { actionTypes } from './reducer';

function Search({ hideButtons = false }) {
    const [{ }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    // In order to keep trac of input text we will use state which is how we write a vairable inside React
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const history = useHistory();

    const search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('you hit the search Button >>', input);

        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM,
            // type: 'SET_SEARCH_TERM',
            term: input,
        });
        //  do something with input ... come back and fix 
        history.push('/search');


    };
```

everything seems fine but this is throwing me error with the same thing ,

> Unexpected empty object pattern, i line number 12:12 ->  const [{ },
> dispatch] = useStateValue();

Comment: Instead of const [{ }, dispatch] = useStateValue(); try using const [{ }, dispatch] = useState('');

Comment: tried using this but cannot come out of errors, if i remove useStateValue it throws an error of of -> (Unexpected empty object pattern) in the console this everything is because of useStateValue

Comment: import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';


export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)} >
        
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>

);


export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);